# Why is post man returning data from a previous account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I had previously downloaded postman and used it for another client. I have updated the environment file for with the client ID and secret for the new client and retrieve the new end points.

On calling

```
{{hostEndpoint}}/hub/v1/campaigns
```

Post man is returning information from the previous account. I would appreciate pointers around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had the previous environment under the same name. So Postman was loading the previous environment.  I deleted the old one and it's working like a charm now

Comment: You should choose it as the best answer so that the question can be closed​

Comment: @Samir need to wait 48 hours to do that